# Replacing gfci and switch lost with wiring

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

I am trying to replace a GFCI and a switch that share the same box, the old one had line and load opposite of the new and and I have now gotten lost.

I have 4 black wires 2 white and 1 ground, hot wire has the green tape and tested no other hot wires and I have paired off the other black and white wires with electrical tape.

I have the live wire connected to the common on the switch, no idea what to connect to what from here! Please help.

The breaker is off.

HD pic
https://photos.app.goo.gl/ryuuHutR5pc6QekX6

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was the old switch a 3-way?  Is this conduit wiring?  Did you put the black tape on the white, or was it there?

Comment: The old one was three way, I put the tape on the white wire, I am not sure if it is conduit wiring

Comment: Good answers.  We're going to need a much higher resolution close-up  picture of what's going on in the back of the junction box.  I tried to enhance it in photoshop but there just wasn't enough resolution or contrast there to be usable.

Comment: Link to high quality image https://photos.app.goo.gl/ryuuHutR5pc6QekX6

Comment: I was able to zoom in on that OK.  Now, on that GFCI... are there any other outlets that you want or need to be protected by this GFCI?

Comment: Nope there is not

Comment: What did that switch control?

Comment: A set of lights directly above none dimming.

Comment: I am sorry the old one was a 2 way switch yet I purchased a three way, I am switching back to the 2 way just to eliminate the variable.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  So the zoom-in and brightening makes clear what is happening. **Imagine there is a physical partition between left and right sides of the box**.

### On the left side

Goes the GFCI.   Since you don't care about protecting any devices downline of here, this is super easy:  Leave the "For Wizards Only" warning tape on the LOAD terminals, and everything goes to LINE.  Almost all GFCI devices allow you to screw-to-clamp 2 wires under each screw.

### On the right side

This is a simple 1-way (as the Brits call it) switch.  2 black wires and you're done.

You're welcome to use a 3-way switch, just make sure you put one of the wires on "common" (the black screw).